# Error when creating new project in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

What i have tried:

1) Install php7.2 
2) Install Composer 
3) run command composer global require "laravel/installer"

But when i run `laravel new blog` the output error is the following:

> The provided cwd does not exist.

Comment: I'd guess you missed the "Make sure to place composer's system-wide vendor bin directory in your $PATH so the laravel executable can be located by your system." bit in [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation#installing-laravel).

Comment: (That said, I find the `laravel new` installer entirely pointless. It's just a shortcut for the `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel` command. I just skip it entirely.)

Comment: You need to use this Command properly in your htdocs folder 

composer create-project "laravel/laravel" project_name

Comment: In WSL restarting the terminal fixed my issue

Comment: try this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76753538/php-artisan-serve-the-provided-cwd-does-not-exist-error). this is solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided cwd does not exist means that the Current Working Directory does not exist which means that laravel new command was unable to create the directory 'blog' because you do not have the permission to do so.

What you can do is to change the permissions for that directory, so the command is able to create the working directory

Comment: How do you change the permission in this case?

Answer (score 0):

in App\Providers\AppServiceProvider in register function I commented these lines of code and it worked

before:

```
 public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return realpath(base_path().'/../public_html');
    });
}
```

after:

```
 public function register()
{
    //$this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
    //return realpath(base_path().'/../public_html');
  });
}
```