# The Provided CWD does not exist

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-5.8

In my application I allow a user to generate both pdf and xls reports and save in my s3 bucket.  This has worked for a while now till today.

When I try generating, the xls generates fine but for the pdf I get this result:

> **Message** The provided cwd "" does not exist.
>
> **Level** ERROR
>
> **Line** 334
>
> **File** /var/app/current/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php

This is my function to generate pdf report:

```
protected function exportPdf($sales)
    {
        $folder = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
        $pdf = \PDF::loadView("reports.pdf.sales",
            [
                "data" => $sales,
                "report" => [
                    "title" => "Sales Report",
                    "date" => Carbon::now()->toDayDateTimeString()
                ]
            ])->setPaper('a4')
            ->setOrientation("portrait");

        $guid = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));

        Storage::put($folder . "/" . $guid . ".pdf", $pdf->output());
        return "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxxxxx/" . $folder . "/" . $guid . ".pdf";
    }
```

In my env file I have setup my FILESYSTEM_DRIVER to point to s3 bucket:

```
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=s3
```

I use the [laravel/snappy](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy) package.
I have cleared cache, restarted my queues, run composer update but still the issue persists.

Comment: Permissions issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52409691/error-when-creating-new-project-in-laravel

Comment: No.  That does not help.

Comment: I have the same issue, but local drive instead s3. How do you finally solved this?