# Cannot create a new laravel project with the command "laravel new" In Process.php line 332:

Tags: php, laravel, macos

I use MAC OS X Catalina. I use PHP v7.4.11. I installed laravel via composer and want to create a new laravel project with the command "laravel new blog"

However, the system responded that

```
In Process.php line 332:
                                       
  The provided cwd "" does not exist.
```

I cannot make that project.
Do you know how to solve the problem?

Comment: See this QA; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52409691/error-when-creating-new-project-in-laravel