# Can't download the PDF file in the due to cwd issue in Laravel Octane server with Swoole

Tags: php, laravel, swoole, laravel-dompdf, laravel-octane

I am using Laravel Octane and `laravel-dompdf` to generate the PDF. This was working fine when I was using the PHP-FPM and when I replaced PHP-FPM with Laravel Octane with Swoole, it says `The provided cwd "" does not exist.`. There are issue with Symfony Process as the current working directory is set to empty. And it's not allowing to download the PDF file. When I dump the response before the download code, the HTML for the PDF is generated properly.

How can I set the current working directory globally for all the Swoole processes, so that I don't get such issues for every process?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when creating new project in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52409691/error-when-creating-new-project-in-laravel)